# Design difference on Android tablet and phone

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am testing the app which I am currently working on. I have tested it on android 10" tablet and a 4" device. There are many design changes which I encountered.

I have used a master details concept of menu system, on 4" phone the menu is always closed and have put a menu icon to expand it, but on larger screen device(10") the menu bar is always open by default.

[image]
Secondly on a 10" tab the form is center aligned and has slight gap to left and right while on 4" it looks great without any margin.

How do I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the master / detail behavior using the MasterBehavior property. Though, how it is currently set up sounds like good default behavior to me, and is likely intended.

I would guess that the padding is similar: one for a larger screen, one for smaller. You can control this by checking and changing the values at runtime. Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom property would likely be of use. [Detecting the screen size](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Device) might also be helpful.